# WPF LiveCharts Error System cannot find file specified

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've been trying to get a pie chart working and was following the instructions from here
https://livecharts.dev/docs/WPF/2.0.0-rc2/Overview.Installation
https://livecharts.dev/docs/WPF/2.0.0-rc2/PieChart.Pie%20chart%20control
but when I get to adding a pie chart it gives me this error (https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiTaq.png) does anyone know how I can fix this?

```xml
<lvc:PieChart x:Name="BudgetChart" Width="250" Height="250" Margin="0,150,0,0" LegendPosition="Bottom"/>
```

This is my current code for the pie chart and both lvc:PieChart and LegendPosition give me the same error

I installed the package through the NuGet package manager through visual studio if that helps